# Chrome marks StartCom cert invalid for wildcard part

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, certificate-authority

My StartCom cert has `CN=opencpu.org` and alt names for `*.opencpu.org` as well as `*.ocpu.io`.

However after the latest chrome update, Chrome marks the SSL cert as valid for the first site, but not the second. Why is this? Does Chrome no longer allow multiple wildcards on a single cert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tricky to see in Chrome what is causing the problem, as the **View certificate** button has been hidden inside **Menu** (three dots) > **More tools...** > **Developer tools** > Tab: **Security**.

There, you could have seen that the error wasn't `SSL_ERROR_BAD_CERT_DOMAIN` as it would have been, if there was a problem in recognizing the wildcard inside *Subject Alternative Name* / *DNS Name*. As a result, **Chrome still has support for multiple wildcards on a single cert**.

The error was probably `SSL_ERROR_UNKNOWN_CA_ALERT` as Google [removed support for StartCom](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html) certificates in Chrome 56 released in January 2017, while the current stable main version is 57. Mozilla Security Group made the [same decision](https://blog.mozilla.org/security/2016/10/24/distrusting-new-wosign-and-startcom-certificates/) at the same time in Firefox 51. If you had your certificate working earlier, you were already using a discontinued version of your browser and skipped at least one main version in your updates.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use start.com certificates anymore. They are not trusted by current browsers, including Chrome, Firefox and Safari, and even currently still working certificates will be untrusted in the future.

https://security.googleblog.com/2016/10/distrusting-wosign-and-startcom.html

[Let's encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a good, completely free alternative, although they don't support wildcard certificates.